# CSS how to start one keyframes animation after other one finished?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-animations

How can i start one keyframes animation after other one finished?

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation-name: animation1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {left: 100px}
  100% {left: 200px}
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {top: 100px}
  100% {top: 200px}
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I want to animation2 start after animation1 finished. I dont want to divide one animation like 0%,50%,100% or use other animation's animation duration. I want to get animation finished information and use it. I don't want to use delay. Is it possible?

Comment: Add another one with a delay.

Comment: I don't want to use this and that, then how to even animate? It's either % and duration calc with 1 animation or simple delay with 2.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. It seems like i can use animationend function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `animation-delay`. If animation1 takes 3 seconds to complete, you would declare animation2 as follows

```
@keyframes animation2{
animation-delay : 3s;
0% {
    top: 100px;
}

100% {
    top: 200px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank but I don't want to use delay because animation duration change based on data from database and there are 5-6 animation based on each other.

Comment: animation-delay is not a property of keyframes. If you add animation-delay to myDiv, it will delay both.